Grub cryptomount with BtrFS RAID: how?
I'm on Ubuntu 23.10, with three LUKS disks (whole disk, no partitions).  Inside of them is a btrfs RAID1.  /boot is combined with /root, inside of LUKS.
Having done grub-update and then grub-install to a separate USB disk, the menu section of grub.cfg looks approximately like this:
insmod gzio
insmod cryptodisk
insmod luks2
insmod gcry_rijndael
insmod gcry_sha256
insmod btrfs

cryptomount -u uuid-luks-hd2
set root='cryptouuid/uuid-luks-hd2'
if [x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/uuid-luks-hd2' uuid-btrfs
else
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root uuid-btrfs
fi

linux /@/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic root=UUID=uuid-btrfs ro rootflags=subvol=@
initrd /@/boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-28-generic

Here, uuid-luks-hd0 is the LUKS UUID of one of my disks, and so assuming that this is what the code installed on my grub disk is doing, only one of the disks gets opened (cryptomount -u uuid-luks-hd2).  That is in fact the case.  On boot, I am asked for the password for one disk, (hd2), but not (hd3) or (hd4).  Surprisingly, I find myself at the grub menu, so despite the RAID array not being complete, it appears that somehow grub.cfg has been read (?)  If I continue booting, it fails, apparently finding the kernel (?), but not the initrd, and leading to a kernel panic.
If, on the other hand, from the menu I first drop to the shell and use cryptomount to open (hd2) and (hd3), then I can continue the boot process and it completes.
Question 1: Is there a way to tell grub-install that it needs to look for more disks?
Question 2: If so, is there a way to do this that doesn't involve typing in the disk password more than once?
Question 3: This is tangential, but even with all LUKS disks open, the search command, when run at the CLI, returns error: no such device: uuid-btrfs.  I'm not sure what this command is supposed to do, as (cryptouuid/uuid-luks-hd2)/@/boot/vmlinux & etc. accesses the files just fine.  Am I missing something?
